# Code doesn't teminate on -1

Tags: c++

This program reads input from user and store value in an array and stop when user enter -1 or number of entries reached to 100.

This code doesn't terminate when -1 is entered.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main (){
    int c [100];
    int i, z;

    do {
      int z, i=0;
      cout << "Enter value the number (-1 to end input): ";
      cin >> z;

        if (z != -1) {
          c[i] = z;  
        }
        i++;
    } while (z != -1 && i < 100);

    cout <<"Total number if positive integer entered by user is: " << i-1;
}
```

Comment: You declared Varible z iside Loop again. int z, i = 0 -> init i = 0;

Comment: The only reason a loop doesn't terminate is because the conditions in the `while` were not met.  So did you take the time to investigate the values of `z` and `i`?

Answer (score 2):

The variables `z` and `i` are declared outside the `do-while` loop

```
int i, z;
```

but identically named, new variables are declared inside the loop.

```
do {
  int z, i=0;
```

The [`do-while`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do) loop has a [Block scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope). This causes that the 2nd declaration of the variables is valid and no redefinition, because they have their own scope. The operations on `z` and `i`, inside the loop, manipulate the variables which are declared inside the loop.

Since the control expression of the loop is not inside the block scope of the loop, the expression access the variables which are declared before the loop.
So the "outer" `z` and `i` variables are "untouched", the loop never terminates and is "endless".

The issue can simply be solved, by deleting the declaration of the variables `i` and `z` inside the loop and initializing the "first" `i` by 0:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main (){
    int c [100];
    int z;
    int i=0;

    do {
      cout << "Enter value the number (-1 to end input): ";
      cin >> z;

        if (z != -1) {
          c[i] = z;  
        }
        i++;
    } while (z != -1 && i < 100);

    cout <<"Total number if positive integer entered by user is: " << i-1;
}
```

Comment: one logical error is there .. `i` is getting again initailzed to 1 in the loop

Answer (score 1):

The below code will work you have problem with the scope of the variable

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

main (){

int c [100];
int i, z;
i = 0;
do {
  cout << "Enter value the number (-1 to end input): ";
  cin >> z;

    if (z != -1) {
      c[i] = z;  
    }
    i++;
} while (z != -1 && i < 100);
cout <<"Total number if positive integer entered by user is: " << i-1;
}
```